# NextJS recaptcha v3 samesite pings

Tags: next.js, recaptcha-v3

the problem with the implementation of react-google-recaptcha-v3, it looks like this, after entering the form with recaptcha, I get a lot of requests [img1] and for some reason after token verification I get score:0.1.
I don't know if it's related, but maybe someone has encountered it before.

```
export default function ReCAPTCHAv3({onVerify}){

return (
    <GoogleReCaptchaProvider
        reCaptchaKey={'key'}
        language="pl"
        scriptProps={{
            async: true,
        }}
    >
        <GoogleReCaptcha onVerify={onVerify} />
    </GoogleReCaptchaProvider>
);
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3NS12.png)